# Can't get express-graphql to pass along passport user field

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, graphql, passport.js

My express setup looks something like this:

```
// Set up router for the /api route.
const apiRouter = express.Router();

// Passport auth only applies to /api endpoints, not static resources
// or js bundles.
apiRouter.use(passport.initialize());

// (more passport initialization omitted for clarity)
// (other routes are added here, also omitted)

// Set up the graphql middleware
apiRouter.use('/gql', graphql(req => ({
  schema,
  rootValue: { db: req.db, user: req.user, req },
}));

// Now add the router to our app
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

Exerything works except that `req.user` is always `undefined` in my graphql resolver methods. All of the other routes that are added to apiRouter can see `req.user` just fine. Other attributes on the request object like `req.db` work everywhere. It's almost as if the graphql middleware was executing before the passport middleware, but my understanding is that the middleware that is declared first also executes first.

Comment: If its returning `null` and not `undefined`, that definitely suggests something has happened to the value. Are you sure the backend has a user value associated with this specific response? `null` is the value its returning from somewhere, otherwise it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said undefined.

Comment: We'd need to see your code handling the request that's passing the `req` parameters. This is definitely not passing a user, but I can't see anything in the `graphql` package that would interfere with this.

Comment: Well, my passport LoginStrategy can be found in github if you feel like looking at it: https://github.com/viridia/klendathu/blob/apollo/server/actions/auth.js. My deserializeUser function isn't doing anything special. And interestingly, if I stick a console.log statement in the graphql callback (shown above), req.user is undefined even before it gets to graphql. And yet it's not undefined in other routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that fetch() on the client side was missing the "credentials: 'same-origin'" option, and thus wasn't sending cookies down, which caused the passport middleware to not set the user field.